# Auto sign google account chrome app

Tags: google-chrome-app

I'm developing a kiosk chrome app, and i'm facing an issue: i can not display drive documents of my domain without sharing them publicly;

How can i auto sign a google account in a chrome app, so i could display drive documents without having to share it with anyone with a link ?

I know webviews tags doesn't have access to cookies and at this point, i have no clue..

I would like to have a "service account": foo.bar@gmail.com, with password hardcoded in the app, and be able to connect it, without any prompt.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2

Comment: Well, after some researches, this doesn't answer my question. I need to make an invisible connection in order to display some drive presentation contents that are not shared but with the "service account"

Comment: I'm not quite sure but try using [Identity API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_identity) **`silent mode`**. If you use silent mode, the API will only return a token if it's possible to produce one without showing any UI. This is useful in cases when an app is doing the flow at app startup, for example, or in general in cases where there is no user gesture involved. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Mr Rebot, I am aware of this silent mode, but it require a manual log in a first time right ? In my situation, users doesn’t have any keyboard or mouse..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no viable solution for this.

Comment: I'm surprised that worked so easily. I would have thought google's login forms would check the .isTrusted attribute on login form events.

Comment: I'm not that surprised, as many people need to do things like this in automatic testing.